¿Por qué if (typeof window !== 'undefined') y no if (window)?
He conseguido esto:
if (typeof window !== 'undefined')
  window["..."]="loquesea";

Y me vengo preguntando ¿Por qué no puso simplemente?:
if (window)
  ...

El segundo caso trae como ventaja que tiene 4 validaciones en este ejemplo: No acepta valores nullos, 0, falso y undefined. Es más corta la línea... Pero como he visto que no es el unico que lo pone me pregunto, ¿por qué lo hacen y qué ventaja tiene hacerlo?

Donde has visto eso?? porque la explicación dependerá del contexto del problema. Lo has visto particularmente con el objeto window o solo es por dar un ejemplo?

En el primer caso se entra en el if si window es distinto a undefined, esto es se entra si window es null, 0, una cadena, una funcion y cualquier cosa que no sea undefined... en el segundo caso se entra en el if si window es un valor truthy... no son para nada comparables ambos casos.

Y por qué en vez de typeof no simplemente: window != undefined? Por cierto, alguien se preguntó lo mismo. https://stackoverflow.com/q/74469149

@Mateo Creo que quisiste decir window !== undefined (con igualdad estricta), porque, así como lo pusiste tú claramente hay diferencias . Ahora me quedé pensando, porque alguien haría typeof x === 'undefined' en lugar de x===undefined ??

@Yussef La principal respuesta que se me ocurre es que en modo estricto no puedes hacer esa comparación x === undefined porque no puedes USAR x sin haberlo definido de antemano.

Personalmente creo que la comprobación if (typeof window !== 'undefined') es bastante (mucho) más declarativa de la intención que if (window), lo cual de por si ya puede tener mucho valor (cuanto más fácil sea leer y entender un código menos se sobrecarga la sesera al fin y al cabo, el código lo escribes una vez pero lo lees muchas más!) pero además esa comprobación "más larga" funcionará siempre... incluso en modo estricto.
Si añadimos el use strict a nuestro código JS, no podemos usar variables sin haberlas definido primero! Ni siquiera para comprobar si existen por lo que esto fallará:


'use strict';
if(!variable) {
    console.log('Sin modo estricto esto SI se imprimiría...');
}



Mientras que esto será correcto:


'use strict';
if(typeof variable === 'undefined') {
    console.log('Este si que imprime y no da error');
}



Como veis, no solo es un if que declara mejor la intención con la que lo usamos, si no que además SI FUNCIONA en modo estricto!

Cuando intentas acceder a una variable que no está definida, obtienes un error de referencia:


if(!variable) {
    console.log('La variable tiene un valor "falsy".');
}



La única forma de saber si una variable está definida o no, es obteniendo el tipo:


if(typeof variable == 'undefined') {
    console.log('La variable no está definida.');
}



Ahora, si el problema es específicamente con window, seguramente se está ejecutando el código fuera de un navegador.
